# Heroku showing an old index.php file instead of the recent one

Tags: php, git, heroku

I have a small app hosted on heroku  and i had  running some weeks ago.Today i updated some files successfully and one of them is `index.php`. However when i open the app,the `index.php` has not changed and still is the old copy.All the other files i updated today are showing the updates i made except for the `index.php` file.

Why is heroku not showing the new `index.php` file?.Should i wait for it to display the new file or is this an error with my git repo?.

I have also tried `heroku restart` and the `index.php` does not show the recent changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed an old file i had `index.html` and `git add --all` then pushed to heroku.The problem was solved.